# Node.js - How to keep track of connected socket objects? (TCP)

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm experimenting with creating a peer-to-peer application with Node.js and the standard 'net' module. The application has both a server listening and also a function that will create a new connection to a static port on another peer that it finds through peer discovery that I'm working on. My question is, what is the best way to keep track of the socket objects so that I can send messages to a specific IP later, or even just to use all of the sockets to send one message.

I tried adding the socket objects to another object that held them, but when I did that, it opened a new connection which caused the application to make two connections to each node instead of one.

tl;dr How do I keep track of multiple sockets without opening new connections?

(Thank you all for your time, the help you give is invaluable for a learning programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket object from the `net` module can be simply stored like any other object in Javascript.  For example, you can store it in a variable, in an array, as a value for a property, etc...

If your attempt to store it somewhere is creating a new socket, then you are simply using the wrong code to store it.  Please share that code and we can help you with the details of what you are doing wrong.

For example, you could do this:

```
var sockets = [];
var s = net.connect(...);
sockets.push(s);
```

And, you would have an array of your connected sockets which you could then process however you like (e.g. iterate through the array and send a message to all of them).

Comment: It was being stored in a global object named 'connections'

Whenever a socket established a connection, a function was called passing the socket object, which was then added into the object with the key being the remote IP and the data being the socket

connections[ip] = socket;

Comment: @SuperbAtBreakingThings - if you want help with your specific code, then use the edit link on your question and paste your code into your question.  Include meaningful blocks of relevant code, not just single lines.  Since it looks like you may be fairly new here, this site works best ONLY when you include your actual code.  And, code is not very readable in comments so please put it in your actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and I changed from using an object to an array that I can iterate through and check properties and it works just as expected now, so thank you.